# how to increase time, through script unty3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 scripts, one is target controller and other one is time controller.
I want to increase time when score is 10, no error occurred but time doesn't increase in canvas, here is the code.

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
  public class target_controller : MonoBehaviour 
{

public GameObject explosion;
public Transform center_transform;

public int score_made = 8;

void Start () 
{
//      cal_board_score score_transform_script =      this.gameObject.GetComponent<cal_board_score> ().center_trans ;
//      center_transform = this.gameObject.GetComponent<cal_board_score> ().center_trans as Transform;
    center_transform = this.transform;
}


void Update () 
{
 //     print ("a");
}


public int bullet_hit_at( Vector3 hit_point )
{
  //        int score = this.gameObject.GetComponent<cal_board_score> ().get_scores (hit_point);


    return score_made;
    //********* perform what ever you want **************
}
public void bullet_hit_score( int score )
{
    InGameGUI gui_script = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("ingamegui").GetComponent<InGameGUI> () as InGameGUI;
    gui_script.add_score ( score );
    time_controller time_script = GameObject.FindObjectOfType (typeof(time_controller)) as time_controller;
    Instantiate (explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);

    if (score == 10) 
    {
        //gui_script.add_time(10.0f);
        time_script.add_time (10.0f); // here i am adding score
    }

    else if (score <= 8) 
    {
        if( GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("interactive_sound")!=null )
        {
            GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("interactive_sound").SendMessage("play_bottle_smash"); 
        }
      }
    Destroy (this.gameObject);
    //****** do whatever to destroy this this object
  }
  }
```

//////////// 2nd script

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class time_controller : MonoBehaviour 
 {
//private datamemebers
private bool is_game_ended = false;

private float total_time = 90.0f ;
private float init_time;
private float end_time;



private InGameGUI gui_script;
private array_start_pos env_meta_script;

private float time_change_at;



void Start () 
{
    init_time = Time.time;


    if( GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ingamegui")!=null )
    {
        gui_script = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ingamegui").GetComponent<InGameGUI>() as InGameGUI;
    }
    env_meta_script = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("env").GetComponent<array_start_pos> () as array_start_pos;
    total_time = env_meta_script.total_time;
    end_time = init_time + total_time;
    time_change_at = total_time - 1.0f;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    if(is_game_ended)
    {
        return;
    }

    total_time = end_time - Time.time;




    if (total_time <= time_change_at) 
    {

        gui_script.time_remain = total_time;
        gui_script.update_time_gui ();
        time_change_at = time_change_at - 1.0f;
    }

    if( total_time<=0.0f )
    {
        is_game_ended = true;

    }

}

public void add_time(float time_to_add)
{
    total_time= end_time+ time_to_add;
}

public void time_finished()
{
    //do what ever you want to end the game
    if(!is_game_ended)
    {
        is_game_ended = true;
        if( GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("game_status")!=null  )
        {
            GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("game_status").SendMessage("end_the_game");
        }
    }
}

 }


  public void update_gui()
{
    add_bullets_text.text = add_bullets.ToString ();
    score_reqscore_text.text = current_score.ToString () + "/" + total_score_req.ToString ();
    remain_bullets_text.text = bullet_remaining.ToString ();
}
```

/// here is method

```
public void update_time_gui()
{
    if (is_game_ended) 
    {
        return;
    }


    string time_to_show = Mathf.Floor((time_remain/60.0f)).ToString("00")+":"+(time_remain%60).ToString("00");
    time_remain_text.text = time_to_show;

    if (time_remain <= 0.0f) 
    {
        manager_script.game_lost_called ();
    }
    if (time_remain <= 10.0f) 
    {
        time_remain_text.color = Color.red;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are simply not updating the text of the GUI element. I'm assuming it's wrapped in "update_time_gui ()". Post that code.

Comment: Please add that to the question, not a comment. This isn't the same function as you posted.

Comment: Method added in question

Comment: Where does `time_remain_text` come from, is it the right text? You might want to `Debug.Log(time_to_show)` to make sure it isn't empty.

Comment: Is the time in Canvas ever displayed? As Zimano said you should start by checking with a Debug.Log if the problem is when you define time_to_show.

Comment: time_remain_text isnt empty...time showing as of total time and decreasing.. it just not increase time..

Comment: And I checked with debug.log. time_remaining.. it showing values but not with increased value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you call that:

```
public void add_time(float time_to_add)
{
    total_time= end_time+ time_to_add;
}
```

And in Update you change it again:

```
total_time = end_time - Time.time;
```

So if I understood correctly you want to do something like:

```
public void add_time(float time_to_add)
    {
        end_time += time_to_add;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly, I want, Thank you maximelian1986 :-)